# Object doesn't support property or method 'match' - jQuery / ie8

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to write on a cookie, it works pretty well on all browsers except ie8:

```
var x = $.cookie(printedcookie); //991_0|590_0|995_0|996_0|564_0
var y = $.cookie(cookie);  // 991~1.20~/assets/img1.jpg|564~1.50~/assets/img2.jpg|201~1.10~/assets/img3.jpg|999~1.20~/assets/img4.jpg

var needles = x.split('|')
var haystack = y.split('|');
var newArray = $(haystack).filter(function (value) {
    for (var ii=0; ii<needles.length; ii++) {
        var needle = needles[ii].split('_')[0];
        var needleRegex = new RegExp("^" + needle);
        if(value.match(needleRegex)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
$.cookie(cookie,newArray.join('|'),{ path: '/' , domain:domain, expires:365 });
```

I am expecting the final output to be:

```
201~1.10~/assets/img3.jpg|999~1.20~/assets/img4.jpg
```

What I am trying to achieve is: check if the first part of each item in var x is contained in y. If so remove this value, together with the remaining bit.

Any help would much be appreciated

Comment: which line is failing

Comment: if(value.match(needleRegex)) {

Comment: Should be `var newArray = $.grep(haystack, function(value) { ... }` instead.

Comment: @raina77ow: Where should your code be?

Comment: try value.val().match(needleRegex)

Comment: Also, `value.match(needleRegex)` should better be replaced with `needleRegex.test(value)`.

Comment: @arun P- Thanks, the code works on all major browsers..Had to use  grep

Comment: @ArunPJohny Two things could be added in your answer: first, explaining the difference between `.filter` and `$.grep` (in particular, in their callbacks' signatures); second, swapping `value.match(needleRegex)` for `needleRegex.test(value)`. Finally, I'm not really sure all this  loop can't be replaced with a single regex (with alternation). Vote to undelete anyway, as the key thing is explained there; have no idea why someone decided to downvote it.

Comment: Maybe `value` inside the filter gets `undefined` or `null` value?

Comment: @nathan742 Why guessing when it's clearly written in the doc: `.filter( function(index) )`?

Comment: @raina77ow ah, title says `Object doesn't support property or method 'match' - jQuery / ie8` this error appears when the property or method is not available in the object right?

Answer (score 0):

IE throws an error : Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'match'

Instead of .match() you should use other alternative functions like

```
contains(),

hasClass(),
```

etc .. according to your logic.